# AutoCompleteTextView with custom view suggestions

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I need to implement an AutoCompleteTextView with suggestions which will be views with two elements : the String (TextView) with the suggested string and an ImageView that corresponds to the suggested string.
As I know so far, my adapter constructor , is called like this :

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,myStrList));
```

In other words , can I put in android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line , my own layout?
I know that I have to re-implement the ArrayAdapter class. 
So far I have done the following :

1. I have created the xml layout file that will be inflated in the overridden GetView method of the adapter
2. I have my own implementation of ArrayAdapter ,Actually I don't know how to implement the

`@Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)`
but I don't know how to get the string that typed from the user and extract from it the possible suggestions and handle all these from the getView method.
Any ideas?? Thank you

Comment: Are you trying to implement an `EditText` with `AutoCompleteTextView`, so an user writes something and a dropdown list appears?

Comment: exactly @nKn .. AutoCompleteTextView extends the EditText class.

Answer (score 0):

> In other words , can I put in android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line , my own layout?

This is exactly what you have to do. Define a new layout with the desired output for each row, for instance, call it `my_custom_dropdown_list.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
       ... />

    <TextView
       ... />

</LinearLayout>
```

This layout would have one `ImageView` followed by a `TextView` in each row. When you declare your `AutoCompleteTextView` you just needed to do something like this:

```
final YourCustomArrayAdapter customAdapter = new YourCustomArrayAdapter(context, R.layout.my_custom_dropdown_list, R.id.your_edittext_id, array_with_initial_values);

final AutoCompleteTextView> myACTV = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.your_id));
myACTV.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply , but I don't get one thing : Ok, the "YourCustomArrayAdapter" will extend ArrayAdapter. What about the getView method? How I will set the corresponding ImageView? Do I have to implement any Filter??

Comment: Exactly. You'll have to extend a `Filter` inside the `YourCustomArrayAdapter` class and override the `performFiltering` and `publishResults` methods, which will determine how to filter and which results should be published (if any) respectively.